# Android: How to know if runnable has finished execuation and is ready for next time execution.?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

It may be confusing to explain for me what i want but let me try.
I am implementing a runnable.
Running the runnable on uithread. 
using the handler for post execution with a 60000 milis.
This works okay for me. but As i have a chat activity user can not wait for a minute to get message. So I changed the post delayed with 5000 milis.
 Now it is fetching the records and displaying the records twice at the first execution.
This is because I am passing an id which is updated in with latest record fetched.

For batter view.
1. If i execute the code with post delayed 5000, it append the data twice to listview.
   because Id is not updated because of first execution of runnable has not finished and  meanwhile another instance has started. May we know if runnable has finished it's first execution or something like to put runnable in queue so that it uses the latest data.

I hope you are getting my problem and request you all to help me out.

Comment: You can make use of AsyncTask which has onPostExecute method so that you will know if the execution is already done. Or you can also make use of intent.

Comment: Thanks @KaHeL I got the same way as you described. I put a variable that will check if execution is finished(isfinished), before every time a runnable get started, if isfinished is false it will not allow for next execution. and in asynchtask at the end of all execution (In post execute method) I set the isfinished to true. Thanks again.